# Baud rate for Ender 3 on Repetier Host (Debian)

Tags: creality-ender-3, repetier

Trying to set up Repetier host for Ender 3 on Debian.

The `/dev/ttyUSBx` is found via `dmesg`, this value goes in **config -> printer settings -> port**.

Printer connects fine, but commands do not send. Status reads

```
xx commands waiting.
```

I have tried all the various baud rate settings <= 250k to no avail.

Is there something else I should be trying, or what is the correct baud rate to set?

`dmesg`:

```
[2828465.418249] usb 1-13: USB disconnect, device number 77
[2828465.418480] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[2828465.418492] ftdi_sio 1-13:1.0: device disconnected
[2828469.171168] usb 1-13: new full-speed USB device number 82 using xhci_hcd
[2828469.329014] usb 1-13: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[2828469.329017] usb 1-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2828469.329018] usb 1-13: Product: FT232R USB UART
[2828469.329020] usb 1-13: Manufacturer: FTDI
[2828469.329021] usb 1-13: SerialNumber: A107MDUQ
[2828469.332455] ftdi_sio 1-13:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[2828469.332485] usb 1-13: Detected FT232RL
[2828469.332756] usb 1-13: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 081: ID 18d1:4ee1 Google Inc. Nexus Device (MTP)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1b1c:1b45 Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 046: ID 1b1c:1b50 Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 049: ID 14cd:1212 Super Top microSD card reader (SY-T18)
Bus 001 Device 082: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 060: ID 1908:0226 GEMBIRD 
Bus 001 Device 059: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 058: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`usb-devices`:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=12 Cnt=02 Dev#= 82 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0403 ProdID=6001 Rev=06.00
S:  Manufacturer=FTDI
S:  Product=FT232R USB UART
S:  SerialNumber=A107MDUQ
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=90mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=ftdi_sio
```

Comment: Presumably `lsusb` shows the printer (as it would be the same as `dmesg`)? Maybe try [`usb-devices`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/usb-devices), I *think* it gives you the speed. See [command to determine ports of a device (like /dev/ttyUSB0)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144029/command-to-determine-ports-of-a-device-like-dev-ttyusb0). If this works, I can turn the comment into an answer

Comment: I think this is the entry
Bus 001 Device 077: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC

Comment: Can you edit your question (not in comments) and post the full output for `dmesg`, `lsusb` and `usb-devices`? I'm most interested in the output of `usb-devices`. Maybe `usbview`?

Comment: Hmmm, so it is FTDI and not a troublesome CH340(G). Interesting. I guess that you've double checked that this the board, by disconnecting the printer, running the commands, and then connecting the printer and runningthe commands again, to compare the difference. Also, it seems that the speed isn't given after all... I was hoping that `Spd` was speed, but yours shows `12`. It isn't clear what `Spd` signifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your firmware configuration may vary (probably worth checking what you have set), but from [The Ender 3 configuration is set to 115200 baud rate #12174](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/12174), the standard baud rate seems to be 115200.

> I think the default Ender 3 configuration is aligned to the Ender3 official confg, which has 115200 so...

Ah, but this is Marlin, and you're using Repetier. Hmmm, maybe ignore that then.

According to [Recommended baud rate?](https://forum.repetier.com/discussion/1455/recommended-baud-rate):

> Normally 115200 or 250000 baud should work find and usb->serial latency is the bottleneck.

Apart from that I don't know. Sorry. I might delete this answer, if it doesn't help.

Comment: I still dont have repetier running, but i took the plunge and bought simplify3d and it's working on 115200.  So, i think that's the right baud rate and this is the right answer.

Comment: Excellent..! :-)